# AOE windows Server/Target and Client/Initiator for Windows7/2012 or later

Tags: windows, storage-area-network, pxe-boot, netboot

I've been using iSCSI for virtual SAN implementations...

I've already used in the past a diskless-boot system based on AOE (32 bits)...

In my case AOE has some advantages over iSCSI for small LAN implementations
(no routing needed, AOE traffic is more efficient)

I know there are a few AOE servers for Linux and working well with Windows clients, also booting windows diskless workstation from Linux Targets...

My question is if anybody knows of recent AOE software to act as Target/Server in a 64 bits Windows OS (7/2012/2016)

THX

here are the sites where you could obtain the windows AOE driver
http://winaoe.org
http://etherboot.org/wiki/sanboot/winnt_aoe

Comment: Dead technology...

Answer (score 5):

There used to be a WinTarget.net AoE target for Windows, but domain name is currently parked so I guess development is over. You might find binaries on CNET and some other file dumps but I'm not sure you want to do that ;)

StarWind had kernel-based AoE target for sure, you might ask them.

https://forums.starwindsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2332

Comment: I had used the VBlade AoE target in the past... recently I had the need to install a AoE target in a Windows 64 bits system and used the outdated (not signed) systems available in the internet but the server and clients crashed a few times and i decided to solve the problem with iSCSI... nevertheless I had preferred in this small cases use AoE... it's a pity the project has been abandoned...

here are the sites...
http://winaoe.org/
http://etherboot.org/wiki/sanboot/winnt_aoe

Answer (score 5):

It may be a good idea to check with Outpace IO. They have an AoE background AFAIR.
Other than that there aren't many folks doing AoE these days. 
I think that lack of vendors is a good enough factor to start routing traffic and switch over to iSCSI. At least there are vendors actively developing and supporting it. 
You can also get good iSCSI targets for free. 
HP VSA has a 1 TB free (no production use)
FreeNAS - speaks for itself
StarWind VSAN Free- optimum option as it does support production use. iSCSI/NFS/SMB3

Comment: gonna check OutpaceIO... 
I'm already using Starwind and Windows Server 2012/2016 Target,,,
Thx!

Comment: Coraid had re-launched few months ago after founders purchased back some stock/IP/assets from the original Coraid company went bankrupt early 2015. They have 100% software now and no hardware. I'd think twice before giving them another chance though ;)